# Should point-free function expressions be allowed when a function is asked for?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, rules

Should an expression evaluating to a function *count as a function* for the purpose of providing a solution when a function is asked for?  An [earlier question on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for) seems to indicate a consensus that it is fine to provide a function literal when "a function" is asked for.

Many languages treat functions as first-class citizen, and allow operations on functions such as composition or binding variables.  What I wonder is if such expressions that evaluate to a function should be acceptable as an answer.

To illustrate the difference, below is an example of an explicit and a point-free function in Haskell, both yielding the same result.

```
\xs -> map succ xs            -- explicit ("function literal")
map succ                      -- point-free (partial application due to currying)

-- both behave the same
(\xs -> map succ xs) [1,2,3]  -- evaluates to [2,3,4]
(map succ) [1,2,3]            -- evaluates to [2,3,4]
```

This seems sufficiently different than the linked question to deserve one on its own.  So, what do you think?

Comment: Why can them be not allowed? It is trivial to turn it into an actual named function (like with linked "function literals").

Comment: Sure, so that's one argument in favour of allowing them. The reason I ask is because I remember some opposition on this before (but I can't remember when, and considering how infrequently I post here it might've been long ago so it might not be relevant anymore).

Comment: Oppositioners may specify explicitly what they do accept as a function.

Comment: I would say that the point-free counts as a function so long as the surrounding brackets are included. Hence `(map succ)` would be considered a function, while `map succ` is an expression.

Comment: @COTO you can just as well do `f=map succ` and have a named function at the same cost in most languages (a notable exception being J, where it's one character more expensive)

Comment: @JanDvorak Agreed. `f=map succ` works too.

Comment: @COTO what is the rationale for requiring the parentheses (or a name)? It is a function-value expression in either case.

Comment: @FireFly: The reason I'd be reluctant to accept simply `map succ` is that it's a function that is only ever used once, for one input, to produce one output. Fundamentally, an expression is just a function that is only ever used once, for one input, to produce one output. Hence a point-free/anonymous function is semantically equivalent to an expression, and expressions aren't allowed in code golf challenges that ask for functions. That's just my take on it.

Answer (score 8):

## Any expression that evaluates to a value of function type can be submitted as a function

I can't see a consistent way that works cross-language to ban functions defined in a point-free style, and in many esoteric languages (e.g. [Underload](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload)), the point-free style is the only one that exists anyway. Even in more normal languages, surrounding a function with `\x->(` … `)x` is just boilerplate, and we normally don't count boilerplate if it's inherent in the way the language works. (See also [this newer question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11074/62131) which covers the ground of whether parentheses or the equivalent are required around this sort of expression; at the time of writing, we're leaning towards no.)

Note that this differs from an expression that evaluates the answer directly (as opposed to evaluating to a function that evaluates the answer); most (but not) all languages draw a distinction, and in this case the expression is just a snippet. For example, in the OP's example, `map succ` is a valid function (it has function type, and doesn't do anything unless you call it), but `map succ xs` is a snippet (because it doesn't evaluate to a function, but rather a value of the base type `Enum b => [b]`). So valid function submissions would include `map succ`, `(map succ)`, `\x->map succ x`, `let f=map succ`, and `let f x=map succ x`, because all of these return a function, and don't actually read any input, produce any output, or the like.