# If your answer is acts differently depending on context, how safe do you have to be?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, rules

This is kind of a follow-up to / re-asking of "[Should point-free function expressions be allowed when a function is asked for?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2441/5138)" with specific reference to the only language I know how to golf in, [j](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j), where the issue is a little bit pernicious and involved. (Note that there was no final consensus in that meta.PPCG question, so it is technically still open for debate!)

I don't know how to ask this in general without being exceedingly abstract, nor do I have examples in any other languages, but hopefully it's clear enough how this applies to other languages where there are parentheses for modifying evaluation order or operator precedence/associativity.

> A little bit of background, for the non-J folk. The J language has an
>   interesting syntax, arguably the main reason it is reasonably
>   competitive against golflangs, called *verb trains*: to pretend to
>   be more like a functional language, you can jam verbs (AKA functions)
>   together without any extra syntax, and instead of throwing an error, J
>   will compose them in a useful, nontrivial way.
>
> More concretely, suppose `f` and `g` are one-argument functions. Then
>   you can write `(f + g)` to mean a function such that `(f + g) y` is
>   the same as `(f y) + (g y)`. (Think of the sum of two functions, from 
>   first-year calculus.) To oversimplify, any odd-length train of verbs
>   does this kind of thing, in a right-associative manner, and we can put
>   any two-argument function we want instead of `+`. (There is a version 
>   of this for even-length trains, too, but that's irrelevant.)
>
> **So here's the issue.** If your answer to a code golf question is `(f+g)`, then do you have to include the parens? You don't have to
>   wrap it in parens to name the function, but you do to use it
>   anonymously, *since it is not a syntax error to omit the parens*:
>
> ```
> answer =: f+g
> answer 42        NB. this works as intended
>
> (f+g) 42         NB. this works as intended
>
> f+g 42           NB. this is equivalent to   f (+ (g 42))   which is different!
> ```
>
> **But it gets weirder.** For convenience, the `f` above can be a noun
>   (AKA datatype like array or integer or string) and J will
>   automatically upgrade it to a constant function. So e.g. `(2 + g) y`
>   is equivalent to `2 + (g y)`. But now if your submission to the golf
>   is `2+g`, then all three examples above will act identically ([most of
>   the time](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d212.htm)). I should note
>   that, having knowledge of the J interpreter, I can say it is reading
>   and evaluating the expression differently in the third case.
>
> And if you want an example of this mattering in a real golf, [I came
>   across one just today](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104976/5138)!
>   If parens are required then my 20 byte solution is (probably) the best
>   possible in J; but if they can be omitted, then my alternative solution
>   is shorter, weighing in at 19 bytes, and ties the current best answer,
>   which is in a golflang.

- A big argument for *not* wrapping in parens is that, when you give an expression, you implicitly assume it will be evaluated as-is, not in some context that can possibly change what is meant.
- A big argument for requiring parens, on the other hand, is that it is only unambiguous when in parens—in J in particular, effectively the only time you can ever omit the parens from a train is when making a simple definition like `answer =: f+g`.

  - One odd possibility that I personally believe is unacceptable is that, if we require parens, then omitting them in a submission means that answer is invoking the effects of the intentionally unparenthesized code.
- A third option, entertained in the meta.PPCG question I linked earlier, might be to require that you add the characters necessary to name the function literal. This is unfair for languages like J and R, though, where the assignment operator is longer than one character, so counting the parens would cost less!

This is code golf, however, and there are (at least) 2 bytes at stake here, so there should be some discussion. I tend to err on the side of caution and count the parens in my submissions, but I think by now I've seen this happen enough times to warrant another look. Like I said, the old meta.PPCG question did not come to a consensus, even in the comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our defaults say that submissions have to be [full programs or functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/12012).

[REPL "programs" are also allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/12012), but they have to be labeled as such, and still have to conform to the [defaults regarding input and output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/12012) (which usually boils down to taking input from a prompt and displaying the results on the screen).

For the specific case you mention, I'd argue our defaults apply to J as follows.

A verb train is essentially a lambda or an anonymous function. Those are frequently used in many other languages, and [they do not have to be named](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478). The argument for allowing lambdas is that they evaluate to a function, which can be stored somehow to use if as many times as needed.

So just as

```
lambda x,y:x*x-y*y
```

which can be used as

```
diff_of_squares = lambda x,y:x*x-y*y
diff_of_squares(5, 3)
```

or even

```
(lambda x,y:x*x-y*y)(5, 3)
```

is a valid Python answer to calculate the difference of squares of two numbers,

```
+*-
```

is a valid J solution which can be used as

```
diff_of_squares =: +*-
5 diff_of_squares 3
```

or even

```
5 (+*-) 3
```

Just like the parens or assignment to a variable are not counted for Python, they should not be counted for J.

Finally, the fact that

```
5 +*- 3
```

does something else (negate 3, compute sign, add to 5) shouldn't matter. When not used as a verb train, `+*-` is neither a full program nor a function, but merely a snippet ([forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/12012)) that requires hardcoding the input arguments to its left and its right. It thus cannot be confused with the verb *train* `+*-`, which *is* a function.

Comment: Another example is mathematica, in which, for example, 'Sign' is considered a complete function definition. 'f:=Sign' is the same as 'f[x_]:=Sign@x'

Comment: +1 for the surprisingly parallel Python example.