# Input in Underload

Tags: support, rules

Since [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload) has no input command, I have some questions relating to hard-coded input:

- Is hard-coded input allowed by default?
- If it is allowed, can the hard-coded input be anywhere in the program?
- Are you allowed to use [Underload's way of storing numbers](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload#Numbers) for hard-coded input in challenges that require number input?

Comment: Can we allow hard-coded input in languages that support input commands?

Comment: I don't think so, since the only thing mentioning hard-coded input is [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10553/87923), and that only mentions languages that don't support input.

Answer (score 3):

It is not so clear, but we've had discussions about similar topics. A first place to look would be [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages) but there doesn't seem to be anything about Underload yet.

From the "default IO for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)"-question it seems that taking inputs as predefined variables is not accepted [[1]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/14327#14327) [[2]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8731#8731) which is also argued to make the answer a *snippet* which is not accepted either [[3]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2423#2423), but at the same time there seem to be exceptions, for example if you use a variable that just stores the result of the last execution [[4]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8580/24877) or if you are using assembly [[5]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/8508#8508) or some form of turing machines [[7]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/7031#7031) (I'm not sure whether this also covers BrainFuck).

One question mentiones Underload in the context of functions [[6]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/definition-of-a-function-in-concatenative-languages), another one also asks about underload and the use of point-free functions [[7]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/should-point-free-function-expressions-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/11077#11077), so it seems writing lambda expressions/pointfree furnctions to make your submission a *function* is the best way to go, because *functions* are allowed by default [[8]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet).

I'm not sure about the numbers, but since unary is allowed [[9]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary) and using the byte values as numeric input is allowed too [[10]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values) I'd argue that the default of using Church numerals in Underload should be allowed too.