# Zsh: Functions and Math functions

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

I have been using functions for Zsh submissions for some time. I typically submit the body alone, as the body can be run as a full program with no modification: `afunction arg1 arg2` vs `./aprogram arg1 arg2`. If recursion is needed, `$0` can be used.

I saw [this recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194683/calculate-the-internal-angles-of-a-regular-polygon-with-n-sides), which is a purely mathematical one. Now Zsh has a math mode and allows math functions which work fairly different from normal functions:

**Normal function:**

```
f(){    # define function
    echo "Hello $1"
}
f world!       # call
s=$(f world!)  # call and capture stdout
```

**Math function:**

```
f(){    # define function
    (( ($1 * $2)**0.5 ))
}
functions -M f        # define mathfn f, bind it to the function of the same name
functions -M g 2 2 f  # OR define mathfn g which takes min:2, max:2 args 
                      # and bind it to the shell function f
(( k = f(4,9) ))      # call and capture
```

**Math function, but in `zcalc` (a math-mode REPL provided in Zsh):**

```
:f f ($1*$2)**0.5    # bind (this defines a function named zsh_math_func_f and binds the mathfn f to it)
f(4,9)               # call
k = f(4,9)           # call and capture
```

How can/should the above math function be scored?

(0) `((($1*$2)**0.5))`: This is the body of the function.

(1) `()((($1*$2)**0.5))`: This creates an anonymous function, executed immediately and discarded

(2) `f()((($1*$2)**0.5))`: This is sufficient to bind the body to a shell function, but it hasn't been bound to a `mathfn`

(3) `f()((($1*$2)**0.5));functions -M f`

(4) `($1*$2)**0.5` with language as "Zsh zcalc REPL"?

(5) `:f f ($1*$2)**0.5` with language as "Zsh zcalc REPL"?

Looking at previous discussions both [specific](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/java-function-literals) and [general](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/what-are-our-rules-about-additional-code-accompanying-function-submissions), I am unsure how this "double binding" of the function should be accounted for, and how it affects re-usability.

---

EDIT: [The logic in question in Zsh's source](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/225b35c9070f94cf79c90c33ffcee84b281f894d/Src/math.c#L1087)

Given a valid `MathFunc f`, if it is bound to a `Shfunc shfunc`, it will `doshfunc(shfunc, l, 1)` and `return lastmathval`. So the value computed by the last arithmetic expression in the function determines the output of the math function. I wrote my conclusions as an answer. I will consider votes as consensus.

Comment: There's apparently at least some thinking that "REPL languages" violate the snippet loophole (I'm working on a meta question to clarify this), so that'd rule out 4 and 5 if that's the case.

Comment: @Random832 REPL languages are perfectly fine, as long as they are labelled as such. It's when they are translated to their parent language they become snippets since they lack the `P` in REPL (print)

Comment: @JoKing @Random832 Thoughts on (5)? After defining `f` in this way, [zcalc can even be exited and the function persists](https://asciinema.org/a/Up6yb48RX6yNDVALqZHyqZtp1).

Answer (score 4):

- Given a shell function `f() (( expression ))`, calling `f 42` in a shell context **will** set a value internal to the shell which **would** be used as a return value **if** a math function was bound to it.
- [Assuming these to be the four criteria a function must meet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/86147), the largest hurdle to `()((expression))` being a valid submission is what criteria 1 and 3 mean in this context. **I claim since "capturing into a name" describes the two steps of binding a shell function and binding a math function, that the anonymous function `()((expression))` is a valid submission.** The expression evaluates to an unnamed function, and it does all the things functions do once it is bound to a name.

In the end, if this is to be accepted, the net bytes saved is... `0`:

```
<<<$[($1*$2)**0.5]   # full program, outputs to stdout
()((($1*$2)**0.5))   # anon math function, outputs as math val
```

This will save bytes when writing a recursive math function, though!