# How do we calculate the length of lambda?

Tags: discussion

Example:

Write a function which returns number passed into it as an argument.

Solution:

```
f=x=>x
```

What is its length?
Is it 4 as a length of the lambda `x=>x` only or `6` as a length of whole statement with assignment?

What if there are 2 functions?

```
g=x=>x/2
f=x=>g(x)+g(x)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless the challenge explicitly asks for a named function [unnamed functions are completely legitimate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478). That means you don't count the assignment either. So your example

```
f=x=>x
```

would be four bytes, and I wouldn't even include `f=` in the post, so that it's clear how I've counted.

What if there are two functions? That depends. If the questions actually asks for two functions (e.g. a decoder and an encoder), count them separately just like you would count a single function. This means that neither assignment would be counted. For instance, if your two submissions were

```
f=x=>x*x
```

```
g=x=>sqrt(x)
```

I'd count that as `6 + 10 = 16`. Again I would not actually write `f=` and `g=` in the post.

*However*, if you define one function to be used in another, like you did in your example, then the first assignment definitely needs to be counted. Your `f` wouldn't work without the assignment, because it references `g` by name. So I would count the assignment to `g` but not the assignment to `f`. I would present the solution like this:

```
g=x=>x/2
x=>g(x)+g(x)
```

and therefore count it as 21 bytes.

Likewise, if a function is recursive, you must also count the assignment:

```
f=x=>x&&f(x-1)
```

Would count as 14 bytes since the function wouldn't work unless `f` was defined.

Comment: I not agree, the function has to be easy utilizable so has to have its name

Answer (score 2):

### Apparently anonymous functions are the norm, so you don't count the assignment

<strike>The length of the lambda is the same as with a full program: the length of your function is the number of characters *including* the assignment. You want something that can be inserted as a line, not proceeding or preceding any other code on that line.</strike>

So, in Python:

```
f=lambda x:x*2
```

Is 14 bytes and:

```
f=lambda x:x*2
g=lambda y:y*3
```

is 29 bytes.

This is akin to the language handicaps: keep it simple and easy to police.

Comment: "the length of your function is the number of characters within the code block" - but you can place lambla witout assignment iside of code block. I so a lot of ansers with such way, so desided to ask.

Comment: @Qwertiy Edited

Comment: The latter has a newline, so it would be 29. But if anonymous functions are allowed for the question (they seem to be by default), then `lambda x:x*2` is 12.