# Are Defaults for Code Golf implicit?

Tags: support, challenge-quality

Recently, I've made some major edits to [a couple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/22/revisions) of [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/78141/revisions), and I sort of instinctively cited the appropriate defaults here on meta, like:

> Write a [program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) to **[output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) the sum of unicorns less than an [input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) `n`**.

Need I do this *every single time*? We've established that authors don't need to mention that [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are disallowed by default, because... they're disallowed by default, and answers that violate them are deleted, and this is a given.

Assuming a given challenge will use the stated defaults as usual, should authors *always* have to cite them like this, using the **magic words** and **magic links**, or can I just say something that *implies* this challenge uses the defaults?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the defaults apply... by default.

From the [code-golf tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info):

> If 1. and 7. are not specified, the following defaults are used:
>
> - Answers are scored in bytes.
> - Answers may be [either full programs or functions (or equivalent)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478).
> - Functions do not have to be named, [unless you require them to be named](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478).
> - Both programs and functions may take input via STDIN or command-line argument or prompt. Functions may also use their function arguments for input. Both programs and functions may output by writing to STDOUT. Functions may also use their arguments or return value(s) for output. [These defaults are based on community consensus.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478)

Mentioning them in the challenge doesn't hurt, but it isn't required.

Comment: I agree. We still have an influx of new users, who have not always seen the wikis or related information before choosing to participate. I think it would be helpful to include the relevant links and references every so often, making it more likely that new users will come upon the information before making a mistake.