# Does code need to be 100% syntactically correct?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I've come across [the following answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85432/12224) in a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge in Haskell, where one has to provide a function:

```
<bindings>
<expression>
```

Now, the last line on its own is a curried expression and as such [eligible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for). However, without the previous definitions, it won't work and results in an error. For example, the following code defines the list of Fibonacci numbers (`f`) and provides an expression to get the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
f=0:1:zipWith(+)f(tail f)
(f!!)
```

This isn't valid Haskell, since top-level splices/annotations/expressions in a `.hs` file are only possible with `TemplateHaskell` (and it won't work if you use `-XTemplateHaskell`, since that's not a valid use of TH either). It also cannot get streamed into GHCi or other interpreters with

```
cat File.hs | interpreter`
```

since you need `let` to create bindings:

```
ghci> let f=0:1:zipWith(+)f(tail f)
```

The only way to create a single expression from this would be `let … in`, which takes up to 7 additional bytes

```
let f=0:1:zipWith(+)f(tail f)in(f!!)
```

which *can* be used as anonymous function ([2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for)), but that seems an overkill to a binding, which takes just two additional bytes:

```
f=0:1:zipWith(+)f(tail f)
g=(f!!)
```

#### Question

Is the [invalid code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85432/12224) invalid? Or are we allowed to introduce syntax/semantic errors and dump some of the work (properly bind, change syntax, or similar) to the user?

#### Personal remarks

Given that answers should provide working code that just needs to get loaded/executed, I think that answers of this kind are invalid. The code cannot get loaded in Hugs/GHCi with `:l` and it cannot get executed with `runhaskell`, `ghc -e` or similar.

However, I think that can lead to *many* Haskell answers needing two additional bytes.

Note that this isn't a duplicate of [Unnamed Functions in Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9031/unnamed-functions-in-code-golf), since that question considers only syntactically valid code. One can have a expression at top-level in Python. It's an error in Haskell.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9032/32014)

Comment: [Also related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/32014)

Comment: @Zgarb: The essence of both answers is that the code should ___evaluate___ to a (unnamed) function, or define a named one. This is fine in some languages. However, in Haskell, such code will lead to a parser/syntax error (unless you take the measurements described above), which is why I'm asking about syntactically correct code. By the way, sorry for forgetting to notify you in the other answer.

Comment: Seems pretty simple: the answer works when run with Template Haskell, or not at all

Comment: @cat: Err, no. It doesn't work with TemplateHaskell. TemplateHaskell only allows you to use top-level splices to create new code. Also, the code that's used to create that splice must be imported. I'll add that.

Comment: @Mego: I don't think so. The incorrect code does not create an unnamed function in Haskell, it creates non-working code. It's another story in Python, though.

Comment: @Zeta: Of course this is of general interest and not specific to Haskell, but the code of the linked Haskell answer works if you split it: A file with the helper functions (`#` and `t`), let's say `f.hs` and then call it like `ghc -e '(filter t[1..]!!) 54' f.hs`. This even saves a byte, because you can omit one newline.

Comment: @Mego I don't think it's a dupe because this is talking about a much more specific (and gray) area where unnamed functions create a syntax error.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan My answer on that question answers this question perfectly - if it doesn't evaluate to a function that can be captured, it's not valid.

Comment: @nimi: Splitting the code is probably a standard loophole. After all, `ghc -e ''` still has to be written somewhere. But that's for another question.

Comment: @Zeta: yes, `ghc -e ''` has to be written, but that's for free, just like `perl -e ''` for Perl. After all we provide functions as answers, not the boilerplate to call them.

Comment: @Mego: Your point *"Any expression which evaluates to a (named or unnamed) function is acceptable"* can be wrought into a strange argument _for_ expressions. If you really meant it that way (that all the code must evaluate to an expression), you should probably add that the _overall code_ must be syntactically correct, not only sub-expressions with helpers. E.g., in this case the last line does evaluate to a function, but the overall syntax is incorrect. Yes, this is nit-picky, but better fix that misunderstanding?

Comment: @nimi: In this case, the actual answer should probably get also visually split, e.g. consist of two different code blocks, which would be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Zeta If it's not syntactically valid, it doesn't evaluate to anything. There's no ambiguity here.

Comment: @Zeta You confuse "syntactically correct" with "can *compile* or *run* the code as it is". This is explicitly **not** required in codegolf, as e.g. functions are allowed by default. You also cannot compile `public static void main(String[]args){System.out.println("Hello, World");}` in Java, but it still is a valid [tag:code-golf] submission and it is in fact syntactically correct.

Comment: @flawr Well, sure, one cannot compile your code, but it's a valid function if put inside a class and fits the "write a function" spec perfectly. The Haskell code above is invalid, regardless how you handle it. Or put another way: by your logic `public static void helper1(int a int b){return a + b;} public static void helper2(int a int b){return a * b;}(p) -> helper1(p,p) + helper2(p,p)` should be a valid code-golf solution, although the lambda is invalid in this context. Maybe I'll need to reword my question, but it's the multi-function/-binding aspect I'm looking after.